# Do ref or roles work within italics in sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to add a :ref: in a line that's in italics.
So, I wrote `` *See also : :ref:`a-page` :ref:`other-page`* ``.

The line gets in italics all right, but the links of the refs don't generate (the :ref: and the backquotes appear verbatim).
I could have thought the asterisk being not separated from the second ref's backquote could break that ref, but neither of the two refs work. Also, assume the targets I put in these refs are valid, I know that because they work at other places in the doc, and when the target is invalid it still doesn't generate a verbatim :ref:.

Are roles (or just refs) forbidden within italics ? If so, where is it said in [the official documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/) ?

Comment: Nested inline markup is a known "weakness" in Docutils/reStructuredText: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible. See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brestructuredtext%5D+nested+inline+markup.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you say that in an answer I can close the question.